# How to translate logical notation to Haskell syntax

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've recently picked up Haskell at uni and I'm working my way through a set of exercises, here's a snippet of one that I can't make sense of:

"Consider the following grammar for a simple, prefix calculator language:"

```
num ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
int ::= num | num int
expr ::= int | - expr | + expr expr | * expr expr
```

I'm confused as how to translate this into Haskell syntax (I'm a complete beginner in both Haskell and functional programming, please be gentle)

I suspect that `num`, `int` and `expr` are all, supposedly, types/values that can be declared using `data` or `type` and that they impose constraints on the calculator. However I can't make sense of either: How do I declare `type` or `data`(not a variable) for fixed values, namely 0-9? Also, how can I put symbols like `-` or `+` in a declaration?

Comment: Why would you need to put them in a declaration?

Comment: There is no syntax for grammars, in Haskell as in most other languages. Note that your problem is not syntax, which is relatively easy to learn, but semantics. If you need to _represent_ something close to that calculator language, you could use algebraic data types: it's a common choice, and allows recursion similarly to the one in grammars. Note that this will represent parse trees, not strings. If your input is a string, you'll need to write your own parser (not hard, but very challenging fro a beginner).

Comment: Anyway, I'd recommend that you take your book / tutorial and see how `data` declarations work, how to specify the constructors (which do not appear in your grammar), how to pattern match on them, and so on.

Comment: Does the exercise say to translate that into Haskell syntax?

Answer (score 7):

Don't confuse a string in the grammar for the AST that represents it. Compare the string

```
"+ + 3 4 5"
```

which is a string in the grammar you've been given with

```
Plus (Plus (Literal 3) (Literal 4)) (Literal 5)
```

which would be a sensible Haskell value for the AST that `String` could get parsed to.

Comment: Indeed. Note that if the AST closely follows the OP grammar, literals are essentially nonempty lists of digits, which might increase the number of constructors to be used in the AST. Of course, it would be better to parse literals into `Int`s and avoid the issue, but since this is an exercise I am unsure about the "intended" solution.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I declare type or data(not a variable) for fixed values, namely 0-9?

You can define a type, like

```
data Digit = Zero | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This represents the `num` in your problem. Obviously we cannot use `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` since they are already interpreted as numbers in Haskell.

Then, you can define

```
data Number = Single Digit | Many Digit Number deriving (Eq, Show)
```

which is equivalent to `int` in your problem. This type represents one (`Single ...`) or more (`Many ...`) digits, which together make a one decimal number. For example, with these data types a number 361 would be `Many Three (Many Six (Single One))`.

> Also, how can I put symbols like - or + in a declaration?

There is no way to put those symbols in type or data declarations. You can use, however, names for the operations, like `Sum`, `Sub` and `Mul`. Then the `expr` of the grammar of your problem would translate to

```
data Expr   = Lit Number
            | Sub Expr Expr
            | Sum Expr Expr
            | Mul Expr Expr
            deriving (Eq, Show)
```

If we would have a string `"+ (- (2 5) (1 3)) 3"`, which represents an expression in the prefix calculator language of your problem , it would be parsed to `Sum (Sub (Lit (Many Two (Single Five))) (Lit (Many One (Single Three)))) (Single Three)`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a exercise about modeling data (without code) the answer consist of adding constructor names to your grammar (and changing literal number to names). Something like

```
data Num = Zero | One | Two | Three | Four | Five 
         | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine
data Int = Single Num | Multiple Num Int
data Exp = ExpInt Int | ExpMinus Exp Exp | ExpMul Exp Exp
         | ExpMul Exp Exp
```

From that, you can write all sort of code, to parse and evaluate expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I got clever, and I declared my AST type an `instance` of `Num`, `Eq` and `Ord`, then defined the mathematical and comparison operators for AST expressions, so that `expr1 + expr2` would yield a valid AST.  Using sevenj’s declarations, this would be written like `(+) x y = Sum x y`, where the right-hand side is the constructor of an AST expression.  For brevity, `one = Lit One` and `two = Lit Two`.  Then you might write `one + one == two` and the operators would generate your AST with the correct precedence.  Between that and abuse of the `let { ... } in ...` syntax to allow for arbitrary indentation, I had a way to write ASTs that was almost just the toy imperative language itself, with some boilerplate above, below and on the left.

The TA grading my assignment, though, was not amused, and wrote, “This is not Haskell!”