# Haskell parse expression

Tags: parsing, haskell, expression

Hi I got a code like this:

```
data Digit = Zero | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | 
             Nine 
             deriving (Eq, Show)

data Number = Single Digit | Many Digit Number deriving (Eq, Show)

data Expr = Lit Number
          | Sub Expr   
          | Sum Expr Expr 
          | Mul Expr Expr
          deriving (Eq, Show)
```

So the idea with this code is to have a string, like `* + 2 3 * 2 + 6 - 2`, which will be represented as `((2 + 3) * (2 * (6 - 2)))`, and then use this to put parts of the string in there types. And of course at the end find the result, in this case 40. The problem is that I don't know much about parsing, so I really don't know how I could parse an expression like this. I have seen some simple parsing where strings are been parsed into types, like person or something. But I think this is a bit more complex. If anyone have any suggestions, I would be really interested.

Comment: Are you sure your input isn't supposed to be `* + 2 3 * 2 - 6 2`? This looks like prefix Polish notation.

Comment: Yeah,  I posted the wrong code, it's suppose to be "Sub Expr" and not "Sub Expr Expr", sorry

Comment: Compare with https://stackoverflow.com/q/46516500/625403 - I think there must be some class somewhere assigning this as an exercise. In which case, the `-` is supposed to be unary negate, not binary subtract.

Comment: @Alec `Sum Expr Expr` looks right to me. The constructor at issue was `Sub`, not `Sum`.

Comment: @amalloy Yep it does. Foolish me. I kept reading it as `Sub Expr Expr` that was previously there.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/19115

Comment: Also your example will be more clear if instead of (6 - 2) you write (6 + (-2)), which is what the input actually represents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While sophisticated parsing libraries exist for Haskell, and would be great for this task, your input format is simple enough that it's not too imposing to parse by hand, with a recursive function consuming the input and returning both a parsed expression and the remainder of the string to continue parsing.

Here's a skeleton of what it would look like:

```
parse :: String -> (String, Expr)
parse (' ':more) = parse more
parse ('-':more) = let (remainder, e) = parse more
                   in (remainder, Sub e)
parse ('+':more) = undefined -- TODO
parse ('*':more) = undefined -- TODO
parse s@(num:more) | isDigit num = parseNumber s
parse s = error ("unexpected input: " ++ s)

parseNumber :: String -> (String, Expr)
parseNumber s = undefined
```

Comment: A nice introduction into the concepts of monadic parsing is the [Functional Pearls Paper](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf)

Comment: Thanks dude, very helpful! I have put in my almost done code at the top of the page if u are interested. Maybe u can't give some suggestion to how I can improve the code too :P

Comment: @iIllumination: please don't do that; keep the question post for the question only; if you have a solution (even a partial one), use an answer post for that. I've rolled back your edit.